# Callback function in user mode vs kernel mode

Tags: unix, operating-system

Why is it advisable to run callback functions in user mode vs kernel mode?

Answer (score 1):

The only code that should execute in kernel mode is that which has been loaded into pages that are protected to restrict kernel mode access.

If you could execute a kernel mode callback function, that would open the door to all kinds of security holes.