# Why is executing callback functions in kernel mode bad?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

Why is calling callback functions in kernel-space from user-space considered 'bad' vs calling callback functions in user-space from user-space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback function in user mode vs kernel mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266834/callback-function-in-user-mode-vs-kernel-mode)

Comment: The answer on the previous question is vague.

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean? Do you mean calling callback functions in kernel-space from user-space vs calling callback functions in user-space from user-space? Or do you mean calling callback functions in kernel-space from kernel-space vs calling callback functions in user-space from user-space?

Comment: The kernel code has a lot of callbacks used, since it's written using OOP.

Comment: @glauxosdever I have updated the question. I am learning about callback functions in operating systems and read that having callback functions run in kernel mode has negative consequences especially security but didn't elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing the user to execute code in kernel mode would be an enormous security risk. That is to say, if a user space program is executing in kernel mode, there **is no** security: the game is completely lost and the user has full access to everyone and everything.

Consider that if you're executing in kernel mode, virtual memory lookups are no longer protected by privilege level. In x86, when in kernel mode, you have a privilege level of 0; meaning you can access anything in physical memory. So, if a process' callback were executing in kernel space, it would be able to do anything it wanted to literally anything on the machine.

Want to erase everybody's page tables? K. Want to instead see what's in those page tables? You got it. Want to zero out kernel memory and cause the entire system to crash? Lolz good idea. Want to hack another process on the machine so that it logs its I/O traffic? Seems legit.

Don't let the user run code in kernel space.

Answer (score 0):

There are systems that support such callbacks. E.g.:

http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/732final/4527/4527pro_001.html#index_x_190

In such a case, your process must have the appropriate privilege to execute in kernel mode.

Allowing code to execute in kernel mode opens the system up to crashes and security holes.